# bootstrap 5 myModal.hide() is not work with vue.js

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-modal

sorry I am here again , I can't fix the problem

> This is my form input

```
<div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                        <input
                    type="password"
                    v-model="password"
                    class="form-control"
                    id="exampleInputPassword1"
                    placeholder="請按登入按鈕"
                    autocomplete="off"
                    @keyup.enter="login"
                    data-bs-target="#login"
                  />
    
                </div>
```

> this is my function, I imported bootstrap modal.

```
import { Modal } from 'bootstrap'
 login() {
      const auth = getAuth();
      signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, this.email, this.password)
        .then((userCredential) => {
          const user = userCredential.user;
          let myModal = new Modal(document.getElementById('login'));
          myModal.hide();
          Swal.fire({
            position: "center",
            icon: "success",
            title: "登入成功",
            showConfirmButton: false,
            timer: 1500,
          });
          this.$router.replace("admin");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          const errorCode = error.code;
          const errorMessage = error.message;
          if (errorCode === "auth/wrong-password") {
            // 密碼錯誤提醒
            Swal.fire({
              position: "center",
              icon: "error",
              title: "密碼錯誤",
              showConfirmButton: false,
              timer: 2000,
            });
          } else {
            // 其他錯誤提醒
            Swal.fire({
              position: "center",
              icon: "error",
              title: "密碼錯誤或信箱尚未註冊",
              showConfirmButton: false,
              timer: 2000,
            });
          }
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
```

> I use this syntax and it works fine elsewhere, wWhen I press enter in the password input box to jump to the admin page, the modal will be hidden, how sould I do ?

```
 let myModal = new Modal(document.getElementById('login'));
  myModal.hide();
```

Comment: FWIW, there's bootstrap-vue lib. The use of Vue with non-Vue libs may be dirty and troublesome

Comment: Yeah I know , but my project is almost finish. Next project I will use bootstrap vue….